# How do I delegate a call to [0..<n] in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, range, sequence

**Background**

For convenience, I used this alias:

```
typealias Deck = [Int]
```

My needs are expanding so I have now converted my code to:

```
class Deck
{
  var deck : [Int]
  // ... other members
}
```

I am able to delegate most of my calls through to `self.deck`, but after googling around somewhat, I am still having trouble figuring out how to delegate this call:

```
let deck = Deck()
for i in deck[0..<5] { }   // <--- PROBLEMS HERE
```

**Question**

*How do I implement the delegation of this call?*

I think it has something to do with `subscript` and `range` (or maybe `sequence`?), but I had no luck googling the  intersection of these two topics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `deck[0..<5]` you need to implement the `Sliceable` protocol, which in turn
requires `CollectionType` and `SequenceType`.

The following example implements `MutableCollectionType` so that *setting*
elements is forwarded to the array as well:

```
class Deck
{
    typealias DeckValueType = Int
    typealias DeckIndexType = Array<DeckValueType>.Index

    var deck : [DeckValueType] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] // just for demonstration ...
}

extension Deck : SequenceType {
    func generate() -> IndexingGenerator<[DeckValueType]> {
        return deck.generate()
    }
}

extension Deck: MutableCollectionType {
    var startIndex : DeckIndexType { return deck.startIndex }
    var endIndex : DeckIndexType { return deck.endIndex }

    subscript(index: DeckIndexType) -> DeckValueType {
        get {
            return deck[index]
        }
        set(newValue) {
            deck[index] = newValue
        }
    }
}

extension Deck : Sliceable {
    subscript (bounds: Range<DeckIndexType>) -> ArraySlice<DeckValueType> {
        get {
            return deck[bounds]
        }
    }
}
```

And then it works:

```
let deck = Deck()
for i in deck[0..<5] {
    println(i)
}
```

The type aliases are not strictly necessary, but they make it easier to
distinguish whether `Int` is used as the type of an array element or as the
type for an array index.

Also you can put all the code into the class definition. I have chosen separate
extensions to make clear which method is needed for which protocol.